# Ionic unable to find target Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a rooted Android tablet running 4.2.2 but I am unable to do "ionic run android --target=device ID". It says:

`ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Target '<device ID>' not found, unable to run project`

When I do "adb devices", my device's ID does show up. I have removed and readded the android platform already. The device is in USB debug mode and it says I am connected as an installer. I have also trusted my computer (Windows 7 64 bit) from the device.

I changed my androidmanifest.xml to have a target API of 17. Am I missing something? Or is it because my tablet is rooted? It is a third party tablet from China. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: If you just do: `ionic run android` what happens?

Comment: @GabrielHobold it will say that no target was specified, thus launches on an emulator

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem when I did update ionic to v2.

What I did was call the full path adb showed when I compile.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/foo/Library/Android/sdk

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

No target specified, deploying to emulator
```

In this case:

```
/Users/foo/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
```

For my surprise my device was not listed there, I have to reinsert it.

Answer (score 0):

- configure the device in developer(USB debugging) mode from about setting.
- Does SDK version compatible with cordova.